# Cannot return result of volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to return a result which is delivered by `Volley` but i cannot manage to do so. This is what i have:

```
private List<Entity> loadEntity()
{
    final EntityValueObject<Entity> entityDTO = new EntityValueObject<>();
    RequestUtils.inst(this).doGetArray(URL, (response) ->
            {
                entityDTO.setEntity(creating entity from json here);
            },
            (VolleyError error) -> Log.d("loading tag", error.toString()));


    return entityDTO.getEntity();
}
```

The `EntityValueObject` is just a DTO which stores the result of onResponse from `Volley`. I did a little debugging and i couldn't figure out why the `getEntity()` method returns null. I can successfully create the entity from the received JSON.

The method signature looks like this:

```
public void doGetArray(final String url, final Response.Listener<JSONArray> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener)
```

What am i doing wrong? How can i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe doGetArray() is network call so It will happen in the background. You are returning entityDTO.getEntity(); which is happening in the main thread. So entityDTO.getEntity() will execute much before doGetArray() finishes its execution.
So entityDTO.getEntity will return null.

You should something like this.

```
private void loadEntity()
{
    final EntityValueObject<Entity> entityDTO = new EntityValueObject<>();
    RequestUtils.inst(this).doGetArray(URL, (response) ->
            {
                entityDTO.setEntity(creating entity from json here);
                **call your method here which handled your entityDTO response / may be UI update**
            },
            (VolleyError error) -> Log.d("loading tag", error.toString()));

}
```

Comment: I just realized that the call was asynchronous and that the result was sent back after i returned my method returned my result. Now that i think of it, it's kinda stupid what tried to do.

Comment: @ffs Happy Coding.